# Left function in Linq like excel and sql

Tags: linq

I am trying to do a LEFT function like in Excel/SQL in Linq however I am struggling to understand the substring in the context of my own code

I have the following code

```
var q = from hed in cxt.SOPOrderReturns.ToExpandable()
join cus in cxt.SLCustomerAccounts on hed.CustomerID equals 
cus.SLCustomerAccountID
join ad in cxt.SOPDocDelAddresses on hed.SOPOrderReturnID equals 
ad.SOPOrderReturnID
join os in cxt.JH_FINALSOPOrderSalesSeachLinks on hed.SOPOrderReturnID 
equals os.SOPOrderReturnID
where os.OrderStatus == "despatched" || os.OrderStatus == "part 
despatched"

select new
{

hed.SOPOrderReturnID,
hed.DocumentNo,
hed.DocumentDate,
cus.CustomerAccountNumber,
cus.CustomerAccountName,
hed.CustomerDocumentNo,
ad.PostalName,
ad.City,
hed.TotalNetValue,
OrderType = hed.AnalysisCode1,
Route = hed.AnalysisCode2,
WAD = hed.AnalysisCode3,
hed.PromisedDeliveryDate,
ad.PostCode,

};

q = q.RemoveExpandable();

return q;
```

on the line ad.PostalName, I have a 4 digit code at the beginning e.g. 0001 - EXAMPLE POSTAL NAME

I would like to just display the first 4 digits of this line but am struggling to get do this.

Thanks in advance

Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Just use an expression like normal.

```
select new {
    ...
    PostalNamePrefix = ad.PostalName.Substring(0,4),
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you :) I struggle to understand some of the basics when using other peoples specific queries. This is now obvious to me. Thanks again.